# Downloading an audio file from MongoDB Atlas (GridFS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, next.js, download

I have an app on Heroku, handling audio files stored with GridFS in a database on MongoDB Atlas.

This app uses Next.JS and express.

For the sake of the question, let us consider this record that I have on MongoDB Atlas in the collection fs.files.

```
_id: 46e737001837a062ce85dd4c
length: 214023
chunkSize: 261120
uploadDate: 2023-08-12T05:09:22.521+00:00
filename: "Audio_2023-09-18:14:39:26"
```

The code below (*Block:server.get('/download', (req, res) => {...}*), part of the file server.js, will be the object of my question:

```
const express = require('express'),
            next = require('next'),
      .....
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Grid = require('gridfs-stream'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      mongoURI = process.env.MDB_URI_AUDIO;

mongoose.connect(mongoURI);

.....


const conn = mongoose.connection;

.....


app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
  server.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '1mb' }));

  .....

  server.get('/play', (req, res) => {
    const gridFSBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db);
    const dataType = "audio/mp3";//"audio/mpeg";//"video/webm";
    // The next line adjusts the content type based on your audio format.
    // The code still works even when commented out.
    res.set('Content-Type', dataType);
 
    if (req.query.afn) {
      const filename = req.query.afn;
      const downloadStream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStreamByName(filename);
      res.set('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename="${filename}"`);
      downloadStream.pipe(res)
    }

    if (req.query.id) {
      const recordID = new ObjectId(req.query.id)
      const downloadStream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStream(recordID);
      res.set('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename=APP-Audio`);
      downloadStream.pipe(res);
    }
  });


  server.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    const gridFSBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db);
    const dataType = "audio/mp3";//"audio/mpeg";//"video/webm";
    res.set('Content-Type', dataType);
 
    if (req.query.afn) {
      const filename = req.query.afn;
      const downloadStream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStreamByName(filename);
      res.set('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename="${filename}"`);
      const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
      // downloadStream.pipe(writeStream) // This doesn't work.
      res.download(downloadStream) // This also doesn't work.
    }

    if (req.query.id) {
      const recordID = new ObjectId(req.query.id)
      const downloadStream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStream(recordID);
      res.set('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename=APP-Audio`);
      downloadStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('APP-Audio.mp3'))
    }
  });

  .....

  // Default route handler for Next.js pages
  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });


  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Use Heroku-assigned port or default to 3000.

  server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

At this point, when I point my browser to one of these addresses:

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/play?afn=Audio_2023-09-18:14:39:26
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/play?id=46e737001837a062ce85dd4c
```

I hear the audio file being played. And this is what I expect.
It happens through the block of code: server.get('/play', (req, res) => {...});

Following is what I want to achieve, which is not yet working:

When pointing my browser to one of these other addresses:

```
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/download?afn=Audio_2023-09-18:14:39:26
https://myapp.herokuapp.com/download?id=46e737001837a062ce85dd4c
```

I would like to download the audio file onto my local storage.

For that I wanted to use what is already working in the block: server.get('/play', (req, res) => {...});

And imitate it (with some tweaks) adequately in the block: server.get('/download', (req, res) => {...});
For the time being it is not working.

I hope someone can see how to handle this issue and help me solve the problem.